# Returing lists of tuple's keys and values

Tags: python, list, tuples

I can understand `zip()` function is used to construct a list of tuples like this:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
y = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'l']
lstTupA = zip(x,y)
```

`lstTupA` would be `[('a', 'x'), ('b', 'y'), ('c', 'z')]`.

```
lstA, lstB = zip(*lstTupA)
```

The above operation extracts the `keys` in the list of tuples to `lstA` and `values` in the list of tuples to `lstB`.

`lstA` was `('a', 'b', 'c')` and `lstB` was `('x', 'y', 'z')`.

My query is this: Why are `lstA` and `lstB` tuples instead of lists? `a`, `b` and `c` are homogeneous and so are `x`, `y` and `z`. It's not logical to group them as tuples, is it?

Ideally `lstA, lstB = zip(*lstTupA)` should have assigned `['a', 'b', 'c']` to `lstA` and `['x', 'y', 'z']` to `lstB` (lists) right?

Some one please clarify!

Thanks.

Comment: "Why does a tuple-returning-fuction return tuples?" - A bit of a strange question. I think you might be the one that needs to clarify.

Comment: `zip` always returns a list of tuples, there is nothing unexpected about it. Doing `lstA, lstB = zip( .. )` just eats that outer list, it's called sequence unpacking.

Comment: @MattH - Yes, that's the question which has to be answered ultimately!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "It's not logical to group them as tuples, is it?"

Yes.  It is logical.

There are two kinds of built-in sequences.  Lists and tuples.

The `zip()` function has *n* arguments, that defines the cardinality of the tuple to be fixed at *n*.

A list would only be appropriate if other arguments were somehow, magically, appended or not appended to the resulting sequence.  This would mean sequences of variable length, not defined by the number of arguments to `zip()`.  That would be a rather complex structure to build with a single function call.

Comment: Aren't sets and strings also built-in sequences?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: sets have an iterator interface, but are not sequences.  They're not indexed by positions.  Strings, while sequences, seem so inappropriate that it may not be worth mentioning them.

Answer (score 2):

`zip` is simply defined to behave this way:

```
In [2]: help(zip)
Help on built-in function zip in module __builtin__:

zip(...)
    zip(seq1 [, seq2 [...]]) -> [(seq1[0], seq2[0] ...), (...)]

    --> Return a list of tuples <--, where each tuple contains the i-th element
    from each of the argument sequences.  The returned list is truncated
    in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.
```

Answer (score 2):

What `*lstTupA` does in `lstA, lstB = zip(*lstTupA)` (or generally the `*` operator) i to flattening an iterable. So doing `zip(*lstTupA)` is equal to `zip(lstTupA[0], lstTupA[1], ...)` and these items are tuples passed to zip and that's exactly the reason why `lstA` and `lstB` are tuples.

Answer (score 1):

`zip` doesn't know what is on the left hand side of the equal sign. As far as it know, `lstTupA = zip(x,y)` and `lstA, lstB = zip(*lstTupA)` are the same thing. `zip` is defined to do one thing and it is constant in doing that one thing. You have decided to break apart the list of tuples in the second statement, so you are the one that is adding extra context to the second statement.

Answer (score 1):

> Ideally lstA, lstB = zip(*lstTupA) should have assigned ['a', 'b', 'c'] to lstA and ['x', 'y', 'z'] to lstB (lists) right?

No, that is not right. Remember, that zip returns a list of tuples, that's exactly the way you expect it to behave when you say

> lstTupA would be [('a', 'x'), ('b', 'y'), ('c', 'z')].

So, why would it return something different in the case of `zip(*lstTupA)`? It would still return the list of tuples, in this case `[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('x', 'y', 'z')]`. By performing assignment to `lstA` and `lstB`, you simply extract the tuples from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to do something stupid like

```
[list(t) for t in zip(*lst)]
```

Just to get lists.

What the 'pythonistas' rushing to defend the braindead choice of lists of tuples fail to remember is that tuples cannot be assigned to. Which makes `zip(*m)` *useless* for matrices or anything else where you want to alter items later.